# .NET Core Windows authentication in docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I want to create a container from my **.NET Core web application** (it consists of multiple projects) which uses **Windows Authentication**. Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
COPY Solution.sln ./
COPY Project1/*.csproj ./Project1/
COPY Project2/*.csproj ./Project2/
COPY Project3/*.csproj ./Project3/
COPY Project4/*.csproj ./Project4/
COPY Project5/*.csproj ./Project5/

RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .

WORKDIR /Project1
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

WORKDIR /Project2
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

WORKDIR /Project3
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

WORKDIR /Project4
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project4.dll"]
```

If I run the container, the website opens up but it doesn't open log in dialogue and user information is missing. What is the easiest way to enable Windows authentication inside Docker container?

Answer (score 4):

By nature, your container is isolated and does not belong to your domain, which makes Windows Authentication a well known issue. The way to achieve this is by using a technology Microsoft introduced recently called gMSA, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831782(v=ws.11)

About how to use it with Docker:
https://www.axians-infoma.de/techblog/windows-authentication-in-docker-containers-just-got-a-lot-easier/
https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2017/09/09/enabling-integrated-windows-authentication-in-windows-docker-container/

Per Mark request, you could also use a piece of code using LDAP:

```cs
private bool VerifyServerCertificateCallback(LdapConnection connection, X509Certificate certificate)
{
    return new X509Certificate2(certificate).Verify();
}

public bool ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password) 
{
    try
    {
        var ldapDirectoryIdentifier = new ldapDirectoryIdentifier(ldapServer.ServerAddress);

        var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ldapDirectoryIdentifier)
        {
            AuthType = AuthType.Basic
        };
        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = VerifyServerCertificateCallback;

        ldapConnection.Bind(new NetworkCredential(string.Format(ldapServer.UserLocation, userName), password));

        ldapConnection.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        continue;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And in your controller:

```cs
if (ValidateCredentials(username, password))
{
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
        new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
            //...
        },
        /*"..."*/));

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(AuthSchemeName, principal);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! So there is no way I can get it working without setting up gMSA?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and I did some researchs not long ago. Windows Authentication protocol like Kerberos will require the client to send some ticket that the server will have to validate to verify the identity of the client, but when you are not on the same domain, it is indeed quite complicated.

Comment: You'll find plenty of resources pointing in the same direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337969/integrating-windows-authentication-in-docker-container-asp-net-app

Comment: Is it possible to use LDAP server for Windows Authentication from Docker container?

Comment: I'm using LDAP, but with a login/password provided by the client, so not using SSO (no password entered by the client). Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes. When user opens a website the pop-up dialogue should open (the default action for 401 HTTP code) and user should be able to enter login details. Login details should be sent to LDAP server. From then on, I should be able to access `User.Identity.Name` in my controllers. How did you do that? I have been stuck on it for a while.

Comment: I did it kinda manually. I have a simple entry point /login that the client calls over HTTPS with its login + password and then I have a piece of code on the server that calls the configured LDAP server to validate the login/password and if validated, set up the identity. It's just a few line of code, but maybe not what you want.

Comment: Can you please share it? It would be very valuable to me.

Comment: I've updated it the answer with a piece of code doing what you ask. It is a simplified version, removed quite a few bit for clarity sake, it won't compile as of but got all the important line to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you! And you got it working by following [tutorial that you posted](https://www.axians-infoma.de/techblog/windows-authentication-in-docker-containers-just-got-a-lot-easier/ https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2017/09/09/enabling-integrated-windows-authentication-in-windows-docker-container/)?

Comment: No, for me this is 2 different solution. One is to achieve authentication without having to enter your password (SSO) and the other is to achieve authentication by entering you password and getting it validated against AD by a LDAP protocol from the server. But it is two different possible mode for my apps.